# How do I make an accessor in tabulator JS work?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Using tabulator 5.5, I've been trying hard to make an accessor declared in the column definitions work without any luck. Here's the accessor:

```
 {
  title: 'example',
  field: 'example',
  accessorData: (value) => value + 2,
  accessor: (value) => value + 2,
  validator: [
    { type: 'required' },
    { type: 'string' },
  ],
}
```

No matter what data I feed the table with, I can see the accessor being called (when adding a console.log in the accessor function), but the accessed value does not change.

```
const rows = tabulator.getRows();
rows.forEach((row) => {
  const value = row
    .getCell('example')
    .getValue();
  console.log(value) // I'd expect this to be whatever the value is with a '2' at the end
})
```

I am either misunderstanding the documentation or the accessors do not work when accessing the data this way at all. What am I missing?

Here's a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-cdn-2djuu5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I haven't been able to solve this completely but... by removing the 'autocolumns' line and defining an 'id' column the 'accessorPrint' and 'accessorClipboard' will work as documented. Still can't make the accessorData function work though.